# Optimize Multiple SoundCloud Objects

Tags: api, object, embed, soundcloud

I'm looking to embed multiple SoundCloud objects on my website -- it's the primary content, but it takes way too long to load. SoundCloud's own website doesn't take nearly as much time to load and they have more than 5 objects on a single page. What are some ways I can speed up the SoundCloud objects?

Comment: Lots of iframes, that is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "way too long to load". Is it loading (albeit slowly) or is it not?

If you're embedding through SoundCloud, the objects should load in the same speed as when you're on SoundCloud.com itself, except for the data on your webpage, which goes through your webhost, then back to the user's computer.

If i don't get your question wrong though, it may be a problem with your webhost's communication speed. Is your webhost a free to use one? Have you checked the upload/download speed before purchasing it?

Or is it because some part of your code the embedding is wrong? (If it doesn't load, that is)

Cheers.

Comment: I'm using JustHost. I've ran many sites through them and have never had problems. I spoke with someone who said it took almost a minute to load my site. On my comp it takes ~6 seconds.

I thought the same thing as you, but when I run webpage test results  over 80% of the data on my site was from SoundCloud. Maybe it has to do with prebuffering the songs?

The objects on SoundCloud.com definitely load significantly faster on their website than mine, but they probably set up their hosting that way.

If anyone has ran sites with multiple SoundCloud objects, how'd you load them?

Comment: Is there a way to have the SoundCloud objects load last? I'm running tests and on the tests they take 8 seconds to load, whereas the rest of the page takes 2. If I can load them last (even though they're in the middle of the page), that'll probably help performance.

Comment: A minute? Usually webpages load under 10 seconds, more than that and you should be checking if the person is/has :

1) torrenting

2) sharing bandwidth

3) maxed their bandwidth

4) opened applications that use too much bandwidth and resources.

Also, you're saying for you it took ~6 seconds. That's fast enough usually, unless you're running on Google's servers which load at 0.01 - 0.9s

Comment: I don't think there's any possible way for the SoundCloud objects to load last, HTML is a file where everything is parsed from the head to the footer, if you get what i mean. :P

Comment: I'll ask him if he has anything eating up his bandwidth. But the tests I ran are saying ~10s for total load time.

Comment: Like i said, a good webpage loads in roughly 10 seconds. And even if you were able to shift the SoundCloud objects to load last, you'll have 5 empty boxes that will jumble up the website's appearance until they load.

Comment: ~10s under what conditions? kbps? I guess if you want to make it load faster, another way would be to optimize the images you use so it carries a lighter load on the loading part. I'm not very sure you could change the SoundCloud objects to fit your desired loading speed.

Comment: Also, another last resort would be to redirect the person to SoundCloud's playlist, i guess.

Comment: Definitely not redirecting to SoundCloud, I'm sure you can understand. I guess it isn't that bad. The more I look at my code I find places I can fix up. Those free website speed optimize tests are actually very useful. 

What do you mean "optimize the images"?

Comment: By optimizing the images, i mean making the image sizes smaller but retaining the original quality (or somewhat close to the original). That takes a bit of tweaking too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got some good ideas -- I think it'll work out just fine.